# PostgreSQL - Table partitioned on date doesn't prune partitions when querying with a daterange

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, partitioning, postgresql-15

Our tables are partitioned by month on the `dt` `date` column

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ta
(
    link_dir text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    dt date NOT NULL,
    tod time without time zone NOT NULL,
    --etc
) PARTITION BY RANGE (dt);

CREATE TABLE ta_201201 PARTITION OF ta
( 
    CONSTRAINT ta_201201_unique_key UNIQUE (dt, tod, link_dir)
)
    FOR VALUES FROM ('2012-01-01') TO ('2012-02-01')
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

If I query with `WHERE dt >= '2023-09-05' AND dt < '2023-09-08'` it successfully prunes to only query the `ta_202309` table.

But if I query using the same dates as a daterange `WHERE dt <@ '[2023-09-05, 2023-09-08)'::daterange` all partitions get selected.

Is there a problem with how the partitions are set up? Should the daterange be converted to upper and lower bounds for comparison?

Comment: It is a deficiency of the planner that it doesn't understand the concordance between RANGE partitioning and range datatypes.  Until that is fixed, then yes you should convert to upper and lower bounds when running the query, if you want to get the benefits of the partitioning.